# Update values automatically

Tags: angularjs

I have

```
 <input type="range" ng-init="overral=0" ng-model="overral"/> {{overral}}

 <input ng-model="value1" type="number" ng-init="value1=10" />
 <input ng-model="age1" type="number" ng-init="age1=30" />
 <input ng-model="postal1" type="number" ng-init="postal1=25" />
```

I need when i update "overral" to 40 for example :

```
value1 = valu21*40;
age1= age1*40;
postal1= postal1*40;
```

or i update "overral" to 80 for example :

```
value1 = valu21*80;
age1= age1*80;
postal1= postal1*80;
```

but i need update automatically in inputs

Edit1:

```
 <input type="range" ng-model="overral" ng-init="overral=0" /> {{overral}}

 <input ng-model="value1"  type="number" ng-value=10*overral />
 <input ng-model="age1"    type="number" ng-value=40*overral />
 <input ng-model="postal1" type="number" ng-value=25*overral />
```

Its work but i need this beacuse i need see first the value original and after calculate with overral if is higher that 0:

```
<input type="range" ng-model="overral" /> {{overral}}

<input ng-model="value1" type="number" ng-init="value1" ng-value=value1*overral /> 
<input ng-model="age1" type="number" ng-init="age1" ng-value=age1*overral /> 
<input ng-model="postal1" type="number" ng-init="postal1" ng-value=postal1*overral />
```

Comment: This isn't a clear question, could you elaborate more with a few cases? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i updated my question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, using [ng-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue). As originally requested, there is no controller.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>

  <input type="range" ng-model="overral" /> {{overral}}

  <input ng-model="value1"  type="number" ng-value=10*overral />
  <input ng-model="age1"    type="number" ng-value=40*overral />
  <input ng-model="postal1" type="number" ng-value=25*overral />

</div>
```

Comment: What does that mean? Did you run the snippet?

Comment: in my code, i have :
Overral: <input type="range" ng-init="overralMortage=0" ng-model="overralMortage"/> 
<input ng-model="value1" type="number" ng-value="10*overralMortage" /> => dont see value
{{overralMortage*10}} = i see value

Comment: Ok, i clear cache and work now, but this dont work:
 <input ng-model="value1"  type="number" ng-init="value1" ng-value=value1*overral />
  <input ng-model="age1"    type="number" ng-init="age1" ng-value=age1*overral />
  <input ng-model="postal1" type="number" ng-init="postal1" ng-value=postal1*overral />

Comment: Your question is still unclear then. You have to describe what exactly you want as an outcome. It feels like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

in controller:
`
if($scope.overral == 40){

$scope.value1 = $scope.value1*100;

$scope.age1= $scope.age1*100;

$scope.postal1= $scope.postal1*100;

}
'
in angular two way data binding,so you will directly update the values in html

Comment: i dont want use controller because, i will have 1000 values for update, i dont want write 1000 lines, i want update in html directly

Comment: <input type="range" ng-init="overral=0" ng-model="overral"/> {{overral}}

 <input ng-if="overral == 40 ? value1*100 : value1"  ng-model="value1" type="number" ng-init="value1=10" />
 <input  ng-if="overral == 40 ? age1*100 : age1" ng-model="age1" type="number" ng-init="age1=30" />
 <input  ng-if="overral == 40 ? postal1*100 : postal1" ng-model="postal1" type="number" ng-init="postal1=25" />

Answer (score 0):

keep your input value as you need.
just like for value1